# End recording without corrupting file

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to end recording of fmedia.exe through a .bat file and before terminating  process Press "s" to stop

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im /globcmd=stop fmedia.exe  ???

taskkill /f /im fmedia --globcmd=stop   ???
```

Answer (score 1):

Found [here](http://fmedia.firmdev.com/recording/):

fmedia can stop recording which was started from another instance of fmedia. This can be useful if you don't have an ability to interact with a terminal where fmedia is running (i.e. you can't press "S" to stop recording). **This feature isn't enabled by default, you must pass --globcmd=listen command line argument to enable it:**

```
fmedia --record -o myrec.wav --globcmd=listen
```

This command starts recording audio and starts listening for commands that can be sent from another instance of fmedia. You can now forget about this terminal window, where fmedia is currently running, and minimize it. This would be instance #1.

When you want to stop recording, you execute fmedia once again (i.e. you start instance #2):

```
fmedia --globcmd=stop
```

Comment: @Eduard if the answer helped you, pls upvote/mark as answer..